# pushwoosh doesn't work if app installed from google play

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play

I integrated pushwoosh functionality inside my android app. I tested it, installing apk from eclipse, and was able to receive notifications, everything was fine. But, after uploading apk to google play and after many downloads, subscribers in pushwoosh control panel is still 1 after 24h (the same one since when I installed the app from eclipse).

I copied paste code from [official guide](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-push-notification-sdk-configuration-guide/), and added a little function to check if `com.google.android.gsk` is installed, just to let emulator run the app without crash but again, it was working in a real device when installing apk directly from my pc.

Is there something to set up to let pushwoosh work from googleplay? Or maybe some known issue I'm missing?

I don't think the problem is due to pushwoosh control panel updating latency, since the one subscriber (me) was counted just after installation, and now 24h are passed.

Comment: Install the app from Google Play on another device and see if it works. There's the possibility that everything is working fine, but nobody is using it.

Comment: @323go thanks for the suggestion but if I had another device I would have tested it, I think it would be quite odd if people install the app and then don't open it even once...!

Comment: How about uninstalling it from your device and installing it from Google Play?

Comment: Hey, you can tell us the name of the app so that we coud download it from Google Play and see if it subscribes to push notification.

Comment: @user1323536 sure! its name is CampaniaSuWeb, I didn't post it beacuse it could be interpretated as ad ^^

Comment: I have installed and ran your application on two Android devices. How it's going with the number of subscribers?

Comment: wow, we were checking just this, it's still stuck at one subscriber...!!! thanks very much...btw, I saw in android console developer under services and api, a link id or sender button. do you know what's that for?